# How to retrieve latitude and longitude from geosparql's wktLiteral?

Tags: rdf, geospatial, sparql

I'm working with RDF data which contains georeferenced stuff, e.g. a POI with the specified location:

```
@prefix ogc:   <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#> .

:poi  ogc:hasGeometry  :geo
:geo  ogc:asWKT        "POINT(48.5 11.7)"^^ogc:wktLiteral .
```

So there's some kind of POI that is located at (48.5, 11.7).
I can use [GeoSPARQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoSPARQL)-queries to work with these locations, but now I want to extract latitude and longitude separately, so I can feed it into a different application which does not support [WKT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text).

```
SELECT ?lat ?lon
WHERE {
    # how do I get lat and lon from "POINT(48.5 11.7)"^^ogc:wktLiteral?
}
```

I didn't find anything useful in the [OGC's GeoSPARQL specification](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/geosparql), so I was wondering what's the best way to extract this kind of data by hand, inside a SPARQL query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's always a bit tricky to do this sort of stuff with regular expressions, and especially when it doesn't look like we have a precise grammar to work with, but I think the following approach works (**note:** This only works for positive values; see [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29828202/1281433) for a pattern that works with negative values, too):

```
prefix ogc: <urn:ex:>

select ?lat ?long where {
  values ?point { "POINT(48.5 11.7)"^^ogc:wktLiteral }
  bind( replace( str(?point), "^[^0-9\\.]*([0-9\\.]+) .*$", "$1" ) as ?long )
  bind( replace( str(?point), "^.* ([0-9\\.]+)[^0-9\\.]*$", "$1" ) as ?lat )
}
```

```
-------------------
| lat    | long   |
===================
| "11.7" | "48.5" |
-------------------
```

The key here is in the regular expressions

```
"^[^0-9\\.]*([0-9\\.]+) .*$" === <non-number>(number) <anything>
"^.* ([0-9\\.]+)[^0-9\\.]*$" === <anything> (number)<non-number>
```

Of course, that's really an approximation of `number`, since it would match things with multiple dots, but if the data is good, you shouldn't have a problem.  If you need to cast these values to numeric types, you can do that kind of cast too:

```
prefix ogc: <urn:ex:>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

select ?lat ?long where {
  values ?point { "POINT(48.5 11.7)"^^ogc:wktLiteral }
  bind( xsd:decimal( replace( str(?point), "^[^0-9\\.]*([0-9\\.]+) .*$", "$1" )) as ?long )
  bind( xsd:decimal( replace( str(?point), "^.* ([0-9\\.]+)[^0-9\\.]*$", "$1" )) as ?lat )
}
```

```
---------------
| lat  | long |
===============
| 11.7 | 48.5 |  # note: no quotation marks; these are numbers
---------------
```

Note that there are other types of WKT points as well, and this code won't handle them correctly.  E.g., some examples from  Wikipedia's [Well-known text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) article:

```
POINT ZM (1 1 5 60)
POINT M (1 1 80)
POINT EMPTY
```

Comment: The WKT definition for POINT is POINT(X Y), so, POINT(LNG LAT).  Your lat and long are reversed here.

Comment: @lreeder OK, that's easy enough to fix.  However, what's the story with that comma?  Wikipedia's example uses `POINT (30 10)`, with no comma, same as OP did.

Comment: Sorry, habit.  I removed the commas between X,Y in my comment.

Comment: @lreeder OK, I'll fix the lat/long issue.  Good catch

Comment: thanks for the answer! I've been working on my own thingy with regex match-and-replace, but your code is shorter (and probably more efficient).

Comment: @Klamann this can be done a bit more simply too (I'm still experimenting).  E.g., the longitude can come from a single replace that uses a group: `bind( replace( str(?point), "^[^0-9]*([^ ]*) .*$", "$1" ) as ?long )`.

Comment: @Klamann Yeah, I actually simplified this a bunch to use groups and replacement text, so it's just one call to `replace`.  Much better now, in my opinion.

Comment: This answer doesn't take into account negative values, the other one does.

Answer (score 2):

Joshua's response doesn't take into account negative values for latitude or longitude. A correction to this is :

```
prefix ogc: <urn:ex:>
select ?lat ?long where {
   values ?point { "POINT(48.5 -11.7)"^^ogc:wktLiteral }
   bind( replace( str(?point), "^[^0-9\\.-]*([-]?[0-9\\.]+) .*$", "$1" ) as ?long )
   bind( replace( str(?point), "^.* ([-]?[0-9\\.]+)[^0-9\\.]*$", "$1" ) as ?lat )
}
```

and the result

```
--------------------
| lat     | long   |
===================
| "-11.7" | "48.5" |
--------------------
```

I've tested the regular expressions with Rubular and the GeoSPARQL queries with a Parliament SPARQL endpoint, and it's seems OK.

Comment: @logi-kal upvote from me, too.  I definitely didn't consider negative values in the original answer.